# Locking a SQL Server table for entire connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I am reading a parameter from a table in a SQL Server database, increment it, do some other calculations based on it then writing some SQL queries with these new calculated values.

```
SELECT TOP 1 fruitId 
FROM fruits WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
WHERE fruitId LIKE '1978%' 
ORDER BY fruitId DESC
```

After obtaining this fruit Id, some math is done and then data is written into a few tables.

I am writing in those 3 tables in a single transaction.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 

BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    INSERT INTO Fruits (fruitId, fruitName, fruitColor) 
    VALUES 197867, 'Apple', 'Red';

    INSERT INTO Salad (saladId, saladName) 
    VALUES 1234, 'Apple Salad';

    INSERT INTO Ingredients(saladId, FruitId) 
    VALUES 1234, 197867;

    INSERT INTO Ingredients(saladId, FruitId) 
    VALUES 1234,197866;

    INSERT INTO Ingredients(saladId, FruitId) 
    VALUES 1234, 197980;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

My lock works fine for the insertion part. But while the calculations are done if someone reads fruitId from fruits, the code for write fails for the transaction commit later as fruitId has to be unique.

Is it possible to hold a lock on the fruits table for the entire connection?

Comment: *Is it possible to hold a lock on the fruits table for the entire connection* - even if this *were* possible - this is a **horribly bad** idea - you need to rethink your strategy, this is not the way to go

Comment: I am trying to write into an older application via this. The insert set is upto 50 rows at times and uses the calculated fruitId. I am new to ms sql could you suggest something i could look up for this?

Comment: @marc_s Thanks! I changed my logic flow and it seems be working fit in one transaction

Answer (score 2):

No, data locks *must* be scoped by a transaction.

You need to lock the table in exclusive mode `with (TABLOCKX)`. Your transaction must span both the read *and* the insert.

Performance will be abysmal.

Investigate [optimistic locking strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).

Comment: Thanks! I changed my logic flow and it seems be working fit in one transaction